# How to achieve scope singleton with Toothpick annotations?

Tags: kotlin, toothpick-di

I have a non-Android app having many similar shards objects, and I want all objets inside each shard (DB client, DAOs...) to be singletons.

For this purpose, I have created a ShardSingleton annotation:

```kotlin
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ShardSingleton
```

and I am creating each shard object inside its own scope:

```kotlin
    var shard1: Shard = KTP.openScopes("app", "shard1")
        .supportScopeAnnotation(ShardSingleton::class.java)
        .getInstance(Shard::class.java)
```

For my DAO to actually be a singleton inside its shard, I have to annotate it with both `@ShardSingleton` and `@Singleton`:

```kotlin
@Singleton // the FooDAO is not a singleton without this annotation
@ShardSingleton
@InjectConstructor
class FooDAO(val dbClient: DBClient)
```

At first sight (and probably out of ignorance), I thought `@ShardSingleton` would have been enough.

Is it expected?

Here is a gist demonstrating the behavior:
https://gist.github.com/bfreuden/a866b21c5a6342a3ce1ed26aa636f9f6